# MySQL - how to apply in where clause to match multiple values?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have values `department=apple, department1=orange, department2=banana, department3=tomato, department4=potato`

How do i tell in the following SQL where clause something like this?

```
u.department = ifContain(department or department1 or department2 or department3 or department4) 
OR 
...... 
OR u.department4 = ifContain(department or department1 or department2 or department3 or department4)
```

SQL:

```
   SELECT 
        u.id, u.username, u.status, callstatus, callername,              
        u.alias as alias,
        u.access1, 
        u.access2             
   FROM 
        sh_av_users u 
   INNER 
        join sh_av_profile p on u.profileid=p.id            
   WHERE 
        u.groups='abcd' and 
        u.xyz='xyz' and 
        (
          u.department='{$anyValueMatchOutOf_departments}'  OR 
          u.department1='{$anyValueMatchOutOf_departments}'  OR 
          u.department2='{$anyValueMatchOutOf_departments}'  OR 
          u.department3='{$anyValueMatchOutOf_departments}'  OR 
          u.department4='{$anyValueMatchOutOf_departments}'
        )
```

Comment: Have you tried IN operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the  [`IN (value,...)` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Simple example:

```
   SELECT 
        u.id, u.username, u.status, callstatus, callername,              
        u.alias as alias,
        u.access1, 
        u.access2             
   FROM 
        sh_av_users u 
   INNER 
        join sh_av_profile p on u.profileid=p.id            
   WHERE 
        u.groups='abcd' and 
        u.xyz='xyz' and 
        (
          u.department IN ('banana', 'potato')  OR 
          u.department1 IN ('banana', 'potato')  OR 
          u.department2 IN ('banana', 'potato')  OR 
          u.department3 IN ('banana', 'potato')  OR 
          u.department4 IN ('banana', 'potato')
        )
```

You can even run a nested query:

```
   SELECT 
        u.id, u.username, u.status, callstatus, callername,              
        u.alias as alias,
        u.access1, 
        u.access2             
   FROM 
        sh_av_users u 
   WHERE u.department in (select dep from departments where location = 'US')
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if that is what you want but you could use `REGEX` like.

```
...
u.department  REGEX 'apple|orange|banana|tomato|potato' OR 
u.department1 REGEX 'apple|orange|banana|tomato|potato' OR 
u.department2 REGEX 'apple|orange|banana|tomato|potato' OR 
u.department3 REGEX 'apple|orange|banana|tomato|potato' OR 
u.department4 REGEX 'apple|orange|banana|tomato|potato'
...
```

but i did not test this.